# Best practices for extending an object graph in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns

Consider an immutable (due to it being an external dependency, such as from a library) object graph such as:

```
public class A {
    private B reference;
    private List<C> moreReferences = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setReference(B ref) {
        reference = ref;
    }

    public B getReference() {
        return reference;
    }

    public addMoreReference(C ref) {
        moreReferences.add(ref);
    }

    public List<C> getMoreReferences() {
        return moreReferences;
    }
}

public class B {
    private A backlink;

    public void setBacklink(A link) {
        backlink = link;
    }

    public A getBacklink() {
        return backlink;
    }
}

public class C {}
```

What are best practices when attempting to extend all of those classes? Let's assume I'm subclassing all three classes: `MyA`, `MyB` and `MyC`, adding additional methods and fields to all of them. Then I'm always facing the issue that `MyA::getReference()` still returns instances of `B` even though I would need `MyB` here. Typecasting everything doesn't seem like an elegant solution and leads to issues as soon as Collections or Generics are involved: `MyA::getMoreReferences()` can't be simply cast from `List<C>` to `List<MyC>`. I considered covariant return types (overriding the return type of a method in my subclass), but this also fails when Generics are involved.

What patterns or practices are recommended in this case? I'm not so much looking for a simple "fix" to specific issues, but rather a versatile pattern to base my class hierarchy on.

Comment: I am still not very clear what you are asking here. Simply subclassing doesn't give you a new hierarchy with the subclass objects. You have to pass the subclass objects in the constructor/setters to create a new hierarchy.

Comment: If my application works with those subclassed objects, it might try to perform `getMoreReferences()` on an instance of `MyA`. Even though the returned objects may be instances of `MyC`, the method itself will still return a `List<C>` instead of `List<MyC>`, which means I would have to cast those objects to `MyC` to access fields or methods of my subclass. The same applies to all the other references: Their interface is still of the "original" type and needs to be updated in some way.